# Facebook won't approve action

Tags: javascript, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to create an Open Graph action but whatever action I use Facebook forced me to submit it for approval.

They ask me to supply instructions to publish actions on my website. I do, but I receive this message (below). I've gone through the instructions myself and it's working perfectly.

What I think Facebook wants is for the instructions to include a Facebook test account, but Facebook only allows admins and developers to use unpublished actions, so this isn't possible.

What's more is that the action is 'share'. So I'm not quite sure why it even needs to be approved.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, because Facebook doesn't seem to want to communicate with me beyond that message.

> Approval Status: Changes needed Please make the changes below and
>   resubmit for review. We are unable to test this action according to
>   the usage instructions provided. Please test your action with the test
>   user created during the submission process called Auth Dialog Preview
>   User. Do not submit for approval unless you have been able to
>   consistently publish actions to the timeline of this test user with
>   the reproduction steps provided.
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

In your app settings there is a section called **Roles**.
This is where you can create (and log in as) test users.
The **Auth Dialog Preview User** is probably there already.